# How to Predict demand on a bus route, considering variaton in kms and price?

Tags: spatial-statistics, time, transportation, spatio-temporal-data, regression

If there is a route (line) modification, I mean change on distance; and also a change on the price for the user. How can I calculate the demand on the next year, considering seasonnality. What would be the best approach to solve this?

- Multiple regression?
- Time Series?
- Spatio-Temporal predictions?

I want to obtain the result month by month

Comment: Do you have any stats to indicate level of transit captivity? http://capntransit.blogspot.com/2011/10/choice-riders-will-put-up-with-all.html

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to do this using a particular GIS software (and version) or requiring a more theoretical response? Either way I think it is best if you can edit that clarification into your question.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall The demand can be categorized on how many of them use de route once time a week, twice, ... , and the whole week.

Comment: @PolyGeo The question is absolutely theorical. So, Iwant to know the approach and the way to solve this problem.

Comment: I think this topic (referred to as "Elasticity of Demand") is  relevant.  Transit agencies have been accused of raising the price of bus transit (used by captive riders) to offset cost of funding rail transit (used by choice riders).

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Transit Capacity and Quality of Service Manual (TCQSM)](http://www.trb.org/main/blurbs/169437.aspx) coupled with historical data for preliminary planning type projects that include, demand, supply, level of service, etc.

Unfortunately, you're delving into transportation/traffic/transit engineering and planning territory at this point. Unless you're doing an academic or research exercise, transit planning is very complex and simply projecting historical data without considering socioeconomic and spatial considerations, regional and local plans will yield inaccurate and false results.

If you're doing an academic exercise, then I suggest, you look at the zoning of the areas by category, learn the TCQSM as much as you can and play around with the results.

From what I understand, you are comparing two or multiple scenarios:

1. Scenario A: keep the current service as is
2. Scenario B: Change a portion of the service
3. Scenario C: reduce frequency/time of the service

Each of those scenarios will have to consider multiple issues, such as the 0.25 mile rule, or if a change in time or location happens, how many will spill to other routes, so if you reduce Route A by 5 riders and hour, you might increase another by 4 so the net loss is 1. Detour times and parking availability are also some considerations. the TCQSM outlines these nicely. In contrast, if the re-route is around an area with low ridership, you might have low net increase in short run but you might have an increase in the net ridership in the long run, if that area gets developed or more transit riders move there.